# jQuery dataTables - dynamic select box

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

How can I make a select box display all the different values from a column?

There's an example of what I need here:
http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

The select boxes should be filled with all the different values from a DB column (or table column).
How can I do this in the add modal window (from DataTables Editor plugin)?

Here's a script that was supposed to do that, but it's not working for me:
http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/34461#Comment_34461

---

Here's the modal window JS script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        "ajaxUrl": "php/browsers.php",
        "domTable": "#example",
        "fields": [
        {"label": "Field 1","name": "field1","type": "select","ipOpts": [   
            {
            "label": "Option 1",
            "value": "option1"  },
            {
            "label": "Option 2",
            "value": "option2"  },
            {
            "label": "Option 3",
            "value": "option3"  },
        ]
        },
        {"label": "Field 2","name": "field2","type": "select","ipOpts": [   
            {
                "label": "Option 1",
            "value": "option1"  }
        ]},
            ]
    } );
```

---

Comment: What is the html looking like?

Comment: Dont use tfoot, you already have thead, also what output is the ajax call giving? Is it an array of arrays? And use "domTable": "#example",

Comment: @Anders Lindén, I have added it, the JS script, is only a shortned example because mine's too large.

Comment: @Anders Lindén, is it wrong to use "#eTable"? I'll use tfoot to insert some textboxes for filtering. Also, what ajax call are you talking about?

Comment: @Anders Lindén, 207 lines, I thought nobody would want to analyse it, so I've posted a shortned version only with the basic information.

Comment: You dont have an element with the id eTable, but its id is "example". The ajax call is the call to ePage.php. You can safely paste 207 lines.

Comment: @Anders Lindén, the JS script that I've posted here is just for example, it's properly configured in my page. I'm willing to add my real JS then :)

Comment: The contents of the php files is also of interest.

Comment: @Anders Lindén, I have added it.

Comment: Well, it is a bit to digest for me. What I would recommend is to shrink this to a minimum, just to get it working.

Comment: @Anders Lindén, would only the select box structure be enough? I mean the solution would be something like a function to insert the different values:  {"label": "myLabel","name": "myName","type": "select","ipOpts": ipOptsArray() },

Comment: @user2230501: have you got your issue fixed? I have similar issue. can you post your final code if it is fixed by any code changes. Thank you!